# python dataframe return highest and lowest values based on a group of results of separate column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['close'] = (7980,7996,8855,8363,8283,8303,8266,8582,8586,8179,8206,7854,8145,8152,8240,8373,8319,8298,8048,8218,8188,8055,8432,8537,9682,10021,9985,10169,10272,10152,10196,10270,10306,10355,10969,10420,10154,10096,10307,10400,10484)

df['A'] = ('TDOWN','TDOWN', 'TDOWN', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP','BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BUP', 'BUP', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BUP','BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BUP','BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM','TDOWN','TDOWN', 'TDOWN', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP')

print(df)
```

For each group of returns of 'TOP' and 'BOTTOM' I would like to return the highest number for a group of 'TOP' and the lowest number for a group of 'BOTTOM'. Below is the desired outcome of I am trying to acheive

```
df['outcome1'] = ('-','-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '8582','-','-','-', '-', '-', '8152', '-', '-', '-','-','-','-', '-', '8055', '-','-','-', '-','-','-','-', '10152', '-', '-', '-','-','-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '-', '10848')
```

As you will notice the numbers in column 'outcome1' shows some of the corresponding numbers in column A. These numbers are the highest of the numbers in 'TOP' group and lowest in the 'BOTTOM' group.

How do I code this so the I can reflect the same results as column 'outcome1'.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can achieve this by doing the following:

1. First we create the groups of `TOP` and `BOTTOM`
2. Then we get `max` and `min` per group
3. We merge both max and min by `fillna`

```
grps =  (~df['A'].isin(['TOP', 'BOTTOM'])).cumsum()
top = df.where(df['A'].eq('TOP')).groupby(grps)['close'].transform('max')
bottom = df.where(df['A'].eq('BOTTOM')).groupby(grps)['close'].transform('min')
values = top.fillna(bottom)

df['outcome1'] = values.where(values.eq(df['close']), '-')
```

---

```
    close       A outcome1
0    7980   TDOWN        -
1    7996   TDOWN        -
2    8855   TDOWN        -
3    8363     TOP        -
4    8283     TOP        -
5    8303     TOP        -
6    8266     TOP        -
7    8582     TOP     8582
8    8586     BUP        -
9    8179     BUP        -
10   8206     BUP        -
11   7854     BUP        -
12   8145     BUP        -
13   8152  BOTTOM     8152
14   8240  BOTTOM        -
15   8373  BOTTOM        -
16   8319     BUP        -
17   8298     BUP        -
18   8048     BUP        -
19   8218     BUP        -
20   8188  BOTTOM        -
21   8055  BOTTOM     8055
22   8432     BUP        -
23   8537     BUP        -
24   9682     BUP        -
25  10021     BUP        -
26   9985     BUP        -
27  10169     BUP        -
28  10272     BUP        -
29  10152  BOTTOM    10152
30  10196  BOTTOM        -
31  10270  BOTTOM        -
32  10306  BOTTOM        -
33  10355   TDOWN        -
34  10969   TDOWN        -
35  10420   TDOWN        -
36  10154     TOP        -
37  10096     TOP        -
38  10307     TOP        -
39  10400     TOP        -
40  10484     TOP    10484
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer is great.  Out of the responses it is in my opinion the most simple and straightforward

Comment: Hi mate. I have another follow up question related to this one. Take a look if you are interested.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793225/python-dataframe-result-based-on-values-of-2-different-columns

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
g = df['A'].ne(df['A'].shift()).cumsum()

df1 = (df.groupby(['A', g])['close']
         .agg(['idxmax','idxmin'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(level=1, drop=True)
         .reset_index(name='idx'))

df1['mask'] = df1['A'].eq('BOTTOM') & df1['level_1'].eq('idxmin') | 
              df1['A'].eq('TOP') & df1['level_1'].eq('idxmax')
print (df1)

mask = df.index.isin(df1.loc[df1['mask'], 'idx'])

df['new'] = np.where(mask, df['close'], '-')
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, your answer works great however the response above has solved the problem in a more simple manner in my opinion.  Thanks again.  I'll have another question today and will share you the link

Comment: Hi mate. I have another follow up question related to this one. Take a look if you are interested. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793225/python-dataframe-result-based-on-values-of-2-different-columns

Answer (score 0):

Alternative answer:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd

# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['close'] = (7980,7996,8855,8363,8283,8303,8266,8582,8586,8179,8206,7854,8145,8152,8240,8373,8319,8298,8048,8218,8188,8055,8432,8537,9682,10021,9985,10169,10272,10152,10196,10270,10306,10355,10969,10420,10154,10096,10307,10400,10484)
df['A'] = ('TDOWN','TDOWN', 'TDOWN', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP','BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BUP', 'BUP', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BUP','BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BUP','BUP','BUP','BUP', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM', 'BOTTOM','TDOWN','TDOWN', 'TDOWN', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP', 'TOP')

# Create flags for groups
c = 0
df['flag'] = np.nan
for i in range(df.shape[0]-1):
    if(df['A'].iloc[i]==df['A'].iloc[i+1]):
        df['flag'].iloc[i+1] = c
    else:
        c += 1
        df['flag'].iloc[i+1] = c
        
# Create grouped object
g = df.groupby(['flag'], as_index=False)


# Get Highest and Lowest
g_max = g.max()
g_max = g_max[g_max['A']=='TOP']
    
g_min = g.min()
g_min = g_min[g_min['A']=='BOTTOM']

# Combine Highest and lowest
dfg = pd.concat([g_max, g_min])
dfg = dfg.drop('flag', axis=1)
dfg['outcome1'] = dfg['close']
dfg

# Merge with original DataFrame
dfnew = df.merge(dfg, on=['A','close'], how='left').fillna('-')
```

Output

```
dfnew

    close       A flag outcome1
0    7980   TDOWN    -        -
1    7996   TDOWN    0        -
2    8855   TDOWN    0        -
3    8363     TOP    1        -
4    8283     TOP    1        -
5    8303     TOP    1        -
6    8266     TOP    1        -
7    8582     TOP    1     8582
8    8586     BUP    2        -
9    8179     BUP    2        -
10   8206     BUP    2        -
11   7854     BUP    2        -
12   8145     BUP    2        -
13   8152  BOTTOM    3     8152
14   8240  BOTTOM    3        -
15   8373  BOTTOM    3        -
16   8319     BUP    4        -
17   8298     BUP    4        -
18   8048     BUP    4        -
19   8218     BUP    4        -
20   8188  BOTTOM    5        -
21   8055  BOTTOM    5     8055
22   8432     BUP    6        -
23   8537     BUP    6        -
24   9682     BUP    6        -
25  10021     BUP    6        -
26   9985     BUP    6        -
27  10169     BUP    6        -
28  10272     BUP    6        -
29  10152  BOTTOM    7    10152
30  10196  BOTTOM    7        -
31  10270  BOTTOM    7        -
32  10306  BOTTOM    7        -
33  10355   TDOWN    8        -
34  10969   TDOWN    8        -
35  10420   TDOWN    8        -
36  10154     TOP    9        -
37  10096     TOP    9        -
38  10307     TOP    9        -
39  10400     TOP    9        -
40  10484     TOP    9    10484
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I tested answer and it works great however the response above has solved the problem in a more simple manner in my opinion. Thanks again. I'll have another question today and will share you the link

Comment: Hi mate. I have another follow up question related to this one. Take a look if you are interested.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793225/python-dataframe-result-based-on-values-of-2-different-columns